# Get exception details from batch statement

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

I've got an application which does connect to a MySQL 5-Server via the ODBC-Driver. Sometimes I'm using prepared/parameterized batch-statements to easily move data around at the server. This is working great, until the moment something goes wrong...

```
INSERT INTO blabla SELECT blablabla;
INSERT INTO blabla SELECT bliblibli;
UPDATE blabla;
// etc.
```

Now if this statement goes wrong, I get a very unhelpful exception:

```
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException
ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.0.26-pro-nt]unhandled error from mysql_next_result()
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.NextResult(Boolean disposing, Boolean allresults)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.NextResult()
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.FirstResult()
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader, Object[] methodArguments, SQL_API odbcApiMethod)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at MyApp.MyClass.MyData.WhyAreYouReadingThis()
```

The InnerExceptions is null.

Am I able to extract further information about the problem? F.e. if I'm not using a batch-statement, I get the exact error message back, but not if I have a batch-statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this would actually solve your problem (more details in DB exceptions), but have you considered using the .Net connector for MySQL (aka ADO.NET Driver for MySQL) instead of the ODBC driver?

You can download the connector from here: http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

**Update:**
Just looked in MSDN at the OdbcException class. It seems that it has a property called Errors which holds a collection of OdbcError classes. Any instance of those classes should have the description of each of the encountered errors. Please let me know if this helps.

**Update2:**
It seems that about a year ago a bug has been submitted to the MySql team related to the problem you are facing: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=49466

The bug doesn't seem to be fixed so there is nothing you can do about it in your .Net application.

In the bug description it is being said that this is a ODBC connector specific problem. I am not 100% sure that this is the case. If you ever switch to the .Net connector please also post a message and let us know if that solved the problem.

Comment: Yes, I have considered using it (not because of this, but generally). But for the moment I'm stuck with the ODBC-Connector, and I'm not sure if this will change in the near future, since it would not only involve changing the Data-Layer, but also all client machines.

Comment: Close call, but unfortunately it only holds the `unhandled error from mysql_next_result()` error. :(